# Where to put and how to test an ESC keydown in a modal component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I built a modal component and added the ESC keydown behavior in a ModalContainer component as following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
}

handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 27) return;
  this.props.hideAuthModal();
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
}
```

This is working fine as intended.

The problem I've encountered when trying to test this behavior is that I don't have an element to simulate a keydown event with enzyme, since the event is bound to the `window`.

I'm also not sure if the approach that I took of having this method in a `container` component was ideal, since this `container` component also contains a connection with Redux, so I'm not sure I should be testing this component the way I'm doing.

So my main questions are:

1. Where should I (ideally) put this keydown event handler (the method)? And how should I implement it?
2. How should I test when the key is pressed down it will call the correct method using jest + enzyme?
3. Should I use this container component to manage both the state and Redux props of my Modal component?
4. I'm not really sure about the container/stateless components usage so I'll ask here too: Should I always keep ALL state management and methods in a container component separated from the presentational component, using it only to receive props and display data?

EDIT:

As @Jackyef said, I can bind the keydown event to the outermost div of my modal component to simulate the event when testing. However I still need an answer for the other questions. And would that be the more correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `onKeyPress` handler to your outermost `div` and handle your logics there. This way, you can simulate key presses when you are testing.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, but wasn't sure it was the best approach. However I still need an answer for the other questions..